# copy values only down an excel sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of values called Creator I need to copy all of the values generated on it (rows 2 through 21 cols A through Y) to a final sheet 500+ times based on the change of a set of values copied to the sheet that builds the values on this one (basically everything stays the same except a UPC in 20 different wood types) however i can not for the life of me figure out how to get a paste special values only with the VBA code that I have

```
    Sub CopyDataFromOtherWorkbook()

  Dim intRow As Long
  Dim intPaste As Long
  intPaste = 2
  For intRow = 2 To 549
        Worksheets("Original Data").Range("A" & intRow & ":K" & intRow).Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Creator Data Filler").Range("A2:K2")

        Worksheets("Creator").Range("A2:Y21").Copy _
        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final Data").Range("A" & intPaste & ":Y" & intPaste + 19)

        intPaste = intPaste + 20
  Next intRow
End Sub
```

If anyone could tell me how to fix it or point m to the information on where I missed the fix online it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you can use `PasteSpecial` as @Andrew suggest, or, it would be better and faster,: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Creator Data Filler").Range("A2:K2")
.Value=Worksheets("Original Data").Range("A" & intRow & ":K" & intRow).Value`

Comment: @simoco although your comment wasnt directed at the bit of code i was actually asking about it was the one that was easier to follow

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
Set rDestination = ActiveSheet.Range("RANGE") 
rDestination.Select 

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _ 
Operation:=xlNone, _ 
SkipBlanks:=False, _ 
Transpose:=False
```

Check this out: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=21846